# Шаблон для рубрики

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, как должен называть шаблон для рубрики http://eco-bitovki.ru/catalog/doma/sadovye-domiki/

И нужно ли где-то что прописывать дополнительно?

Answer (score 1):

Если слаг рубрики `sadovye-domiki`, то файл шаблона должен называться `category-sadovye-domiki`. 
Узнать, в какой последовательности `Wordpress` ищет шаблоны, можно тут: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png
В вашем случае цепочка будет такая: 
`Archive page -> Category archive -> category-$slug.php`.

Comment: Еще дополню. В вашем случае это не потребуется, но на будущее почитайте про хук `template_include`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я так пробовал, но не работает, все равно подхватывает archive.php ((

Comment: Проверяли слаг? Место, где лежит файл?

Comment: Файл в корне. Пробовал еще такое название taxonomy-catalog-sadovye-domiki.php - не работает. Как проверить слаг?

Comment: Файл должен лежать в папке темы. Слаг - "Ярлык" на странице рубрик. В принципе, если выводит нужные домики, то слаг указан верно.

Comment: Как вариант - использовать вышеупомянутый хук. `add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1 );
function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
 if( is_category( $slug ) ){ $template_path = <путь до файла>; } return $template_path; }`